# php wont return same as sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

ok, so I have a search script with is sort of working but I dont get the results I want.

when i run the query in php it doesnt result anything.

```
$searchStr = htmlspecialchars($searchStr); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM steamitems WHERE steamid='" . $id . "' AND name LIKE '%".$searchStr."%'";
$r_query = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
```

but if I run the exact same output as $sql (`SELECT * FROM steamitems WHERE steamid='76561198196240283' AND name LIKE '%sawed%'`) in phpmyadmin it returns the correct result..

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I obviously print the results here

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r_query)){ 
      echo $row["assetid"];
      echo $row["name];
  }
```

Comment: Did you verify your variables contain the value you expect them to? I bet they don't.

Comment: you need to look into fetchAll()

Comment: Random advice: You are using double quotes `"` for your sql var. This means you can interpolate variables instead of concatenating them. You should do this as it becomes much easier to visually parse and see what is going on. eg `$sql = "SELECT * FROM steamitems WHERE steamid='{$id}' AND name LIKE '%{$searchStr}%'";`

Comment: @JohnConde I did echo $sql and then copied that output and ran in phpmyadmin. The variables work.

Comment: Your code executes the query, but does not fetch and print out its results.

Comment: @Shadow I do, but the result is empty so it doesn't matter to show that part of the code.

Comment: And how should we know that you have that code, just decided not to include it? Pls do not assume that we know sg that you are not telling us! Your updated code does not have any error checking. Do you have that in your code?

Comment: No @amflare, you shouldn't do that at all. [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Of course. But this is not the time or place to rewrite that code according to modern standards. The risks you mention are the same whether OP follows my advice or not. I'm speaking more in a general manner when dealing with PHP and strings and variables.

Comment: Let's not teach/propagate sloppy and dangerous coding practices @amflare. If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Interpolation is not sloppy or dangerous.

Comment: In a SQL query it absolutely is @amflare.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - So is concatenation. Instead of trying to browbeat me for random advice, perhaps you should put that effort into educating OP.

Comment: I did - notice the links I posted in response to you about SQL Injection attacks ;) If you think I am browbeating you, you are very mistaken. You would know it if I were.

Comment: I would say interpolation is sometimes ok for queries. It's not in this instance though. As for the actual issue here, everything you posted looks fine to me. I would make sure that `$link` is an active connection and I might even take the where out of the query just to see if it would return anything.